# What time-zone is used for determining a day?

Tags: discussion

The Suffrage badge states the following

> Used 30 votes in a day

Does this mean 30 votes in any 24 hour period or is there a specific time-zone used by Stack Exchange to determine when a one day ends and another starts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All StackOverflow and StackExchange time and calculations are based on Coordinated Universal Time, abbreviated UTC. See this thread, and any of the dozens of related ones, to understand why, AND, why this is confusing to many people:
[What time zone do sos servers operate in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-sos-servers-operate-in)
If you hover over your user name in the top bar, you'll see UTC time in the bottom left corner of the activity summary.

Comment: For background info, [Wikipedia page on "UTC"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29).

Answer (score 1):

The 30 votes have to been in the UTC day I believe.  So, you have to vote 30 times between 00:00 and 23:59 utc.